# Posting JSON via Jersey

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jaxb2

I have this code

```
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);
    client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter(adminUser, adminPass));
    client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out));

    WebResource service = client.resource(baseURL);
    ClientResponse clientResponse = service.path("api")
            .path("v1")
            .path("shoppers")
            .path(orderId)
            .path("status.json").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(ClientResponse.class, request);
```

Whenever i try to post a JSON requestl ike that, I am getting `HTTP 415` error response. A little digging into this issue revealed that JERSEY isn't marshalling my object properly. By adding the `LoggingFilter`, I can see that in request body, the `JAXBObject` was marshed to `XML` and not `JSON`.

Is it a known behaviour of JERSEY? What should i do here ?

Comment: You're not telling it to marshal it as JSON anywhere so why would you assume it is?

Comment: i thought it was a build-in behaviour based on content type. anyways, how to do that ? Even here, he isn't telling Jersey to marshal it into JSON http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html. It is being done automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to call [`type()`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.5/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/client/PartialRequestBuilder.html#type%28javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType%29) on your request to set the content-type (I assume Jersey does something smart with this):

```
.path("status.json")
.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) // <-- This line
.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
.post(ClientResponse.class, request);
```

[Other resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2121390/how-to-generate-json-from-a-jersey-resource) indicate that you may need to do this manually with an [`ObjectMapper`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.9/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonStr = mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonObj);
```

Comment: ah, sometimes you miss the basic thing when you try to re-write the code by yourself. Gracia